# Formula for the n-th iteration of rotational operator

Tags: operators, vectors

Hello i was wondering since we have a formula for $$\operatorname{rot}(\operatorname{rot}(A))=\operatorname{grad}(\operatorname{div}(A))-\Delta(A)$$
Is there any nice generalisation of it ?
Thanks

Comment: How is this a physics question rather than a pure [math.SE] question?

Comment: Recall that $\text{curl} = \# \circ \star \circ d \circ \flat$. So taking into account that $d\circ d=0$ and $\delta \circ \delta = 0$ with $\delta = \star d \star$, some simplifications seem to arise.

Comment: If you are comfortable in contracting Levi-Civita symbols, your can readily produce all your answers--and your questions.

Comment: The [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operators_in_differential_geometry#Hodge_Laplacian) is defined as $\triangle = d\delta  +\delta d$ on differential forms. This gives the usual formulas for functions and vector fields (identified with $1$-forms using the metric)